# Spring web application private room creation tips?

Tags: spring, web-applications

I am developing and web application using spring framework and I have to do something totally new to me.

After one user logs in (part done),he can create a room. At the creation of the room he can invite another 1-2 users( select them from a list of all logged in users).

Since is my first time when i try to do something like this , I don't really know how can I simulate the create room process.Is it all done using sessions? Another aspect is how should i invite another user to my room.

So, I need some tips on what should I do research before i could start the coding part.I tried to find some examples on the web , but i couldn't find anything. Any ideas, tips would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.